# Transform NOT IN to NOT EXISTS doesn't return the same

Tags: sql, oracle

I trying to have fun transform a NOT IN  query to NOT EXISTS . But NOT EXISTS doesn't return what I expect.. what I'm doing wrong?

NOT IN QUERY:

```
SELECT BLC.LABEL_COLECCTIONS_ID
     FROM  BET_LABELS BL, 
        BET_LABEL_SEASONS BLS, 
        BET_LABEL_COLLECTIONS BLC
        WHERE BLC.LABEL_ID = BL.LABEL_ID 
        AND BL.LABEL_ID = BLS.LABEL_ID 
        AND blc.collection_id = 6470
        AND BLS.SEASON_ID = 71
        AND blc.label_colecctions_id NOT IN (
                                          SELECT gp.label_colecctions_id
                                          FROM GPE_PRICES GP, gpe_collection_assignements GCA
                                          WHERE gp.collection_assignement_id = GCA.collection_assignement_id
                                          AND GCA.collection_assignement_id = 101591665 and gca.season_id = 71
                                          );
```

NOT EXIST:

```
SELECT BLC.LABEL_COLECCTIONS_ID 
FROM BET_LABELS BL,
BET_LABEL_SEASONS BLS,
BET_LABEL_COLLECTIONS BLC
WHERE BLC.LABEL_ID    = BL.LABEL_ID 
AND BL.LABEL_ID       = BLS.LABEL_ID 
AND BLC.COLLECTION_ID = 6470 
AND BLS.SEASON_ID     = 71
AND NOT EXISTS (       
                 SELECT GP.LABEL_COLECCTIONS_ID 
                 FROM GPE_PRICES GP,
                 GPE_COLLECTION_ASSIGNEMENTS GCA
                 WHERE GP.COLLECTION_ASSIGNEMENT_ID =    GCA.COLLECTION_ASSIGNEMENT_ID
                 AND GCA.COLLECTION_ASSIGNEMENT_ID  = 101591665
                 AND GCA.SEASON_ID                  = 71
              );
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include LABEL_COLECCTIONS_ID in the condition

```
SELECT BLC.LABEL_COLECCTIONS_ID 
FROM BET_LABELS BL,
BET_LABEL_SEASONS BLS,
BET_LABEL_COLLECTIONS BLC
WHERE BLC.LABEL_ID    = BL.LABEL_ID 
AND BL.LABEL_ID       = BLS.LABEL_ID 
AND BLC.COLLECTION_ID = 6470 
AND BLS.SEASON_ID     = 71
AND NOT EXISTS (       
                 SELECT * 
                 FROM GPE_PRICES GP,
                 GPE_COLLECTION_ASSIGNEMENTS GCA
                 WHERE GP.COLLECTION_ASSIGNEMENT_ID =    GCA.COLLECTION_ASSIGNEMENT_ID
                 AND GCA.COLLECTION_ASSIGNEMENT_ID  = 101591665
                 AND GCA.SEASON_ID                  = 71
                 and GP.LABEL_COLECCTIONS_ID=blc.label_colecctions_id 
              );
```